# How can I center screen on IntelliJ if screen is not split?

Tags: intellij-idea

When only one file is open and project structure (on the left) is closed, the text is all the way to the left of the screen, which is annoying imo. Is there a way to make text be centered on the screen?

Comment: You can try the [distraction free mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/intellij-idea-viewing-modes.html#d991810e127) although I'm not sure it's 100% what you're looking for

Comment: Hmm, I wanted it to just center the text, but I'm guessing there is no such feature and Distraction free mode seems close enough to what I wanted. Thank you.